# Why won't my character jump in pygame/python

Tags: python, pygame

This is my first Pygame game that I'm making.

I am planning on making a 2 player fighting game with basic squares/blocks.

I am now trying to implement jumping into the first character and in my eyes all the logic looks correct and I have got no errors at the moment. However, when I try pressing `w` to jump, nothing happens!

All help appreciated. (P.S if you're wondering why I have no classes in my script, I cannot seem to get my head around classes and they confuse me a lot :P) Thanks and here's my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

#Sets up 8 bit colours
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
lightblue = (180,235,255)
grassgreen =(20,200,50)

#Sets up pygame window
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Block Fighter')

gameExit = False

#Variables
x = 50
y = 480
x_change = 0
y_change = 0

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Main Game Loop
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x_change = -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                x_change = 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                y_change = -5
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                x_change = 0

    if y <= 480:
        onGround = False
    else:
        onGround = True
    if onGround == False:
        y_change = 5
    if onGround == True:
        y_change = 0


    x += x_change
    y += y_change

    gameDisplay.fill(lightblue)
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, grassgreen, [1000,600,-1000,-100])
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, black, [x,y,20,20])
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(40)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: Definitely put some effort into understanding classes.  If you're going to write Python (or really most languages) it's crucial.  It will also improve your general understanding of how object oriented programming works, and thus help you with everything.

Comment: As for your actual problem, if you put a `print("changed")` in your code after the line that says `y_change = -5`, does it print "changed" when you push w?

Comment: @Jake Biggs: Johan just answered your question. :D

Answer (score 4):

When you press w to jump, the game will change the value of `y_change` to `-5` as intended. When the event queue has been processed, it goes on to this block:

```
if y <= 480:
        onGround = False
else:
    onGround = True
if onGround == False:
    y_change = 5
if onGround == True:
    y_change = 0
```

Your physics has not been simulated yet at this point, so your character is still on the ground. In other words, `onGround` is still `True`. Therefore, the `if onGround == True: y_change = 0` code gets executed, and `y_change` is set back to 0 again.

After this has happened, your physics simulation happens, and `y_change` is now 0. This is why your character does not jump. You need to redesign your code so that the game realizes that your character is starting to jump when it's checking whether he's on the ground or not. Good luck with your game!